# The AOT compilation persist if the buildOptimizer option is in false?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-aot

I'm working in a project that's require the AOT compilation but for some particular feature into the project I need to turn to false the option `buildOptimizer` into `angular.json`

My question is:
The AOT compilation persist if I turn to false the property `buildOptimizer`?

```
"optimization": true,
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": false,
"extractCss": true,
"namedChunks": false,
"aot": true,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": false
```

Comment: The short answer is yes

Comment: And the long answer?

Comment: And the long answer is the `buildOptimizer` option has nothing to do with AOT compilation which is set to `true` in your config

Comment: I'm asking because in the documentation has the following information:
`--buildOptimizer=true|false 
Enables '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer' optimizations when using the 'aot' option.`

Comment: Ah.. I see. That's because buildOptimizer cannot be used without aot.  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/15b208fa958643599b3cd020048eb49c27ba5e3a/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/browser/index.ts#L116-L119. But we can use aot without buildOptimizer

Comment: Do you want to post as answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189702/discussion-between-abel-valdez-and-yurzui).